# How can I add a border to CPView?

Tags: cappuccino, objective-j

I'm new to cappuccino, but I'm picking the language up fast. How can I add a border to a CPView? Or should I be using a different object instead? I've got a CPView that I'm using as a content view, and it needs a border. I also have several CPImageViews that need borders as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put it in a CPBox.